# Error "Volley-AuthFailuereError" en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-volley

Estoy haciendo una petición a una api donde le mando una key por el header a esta api y me responde con info pero al hacer la petición me aparece este error : com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Este es el codigo de la petición.

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://io.adafruit.com/api/v2/Juan8293/feeds/grupoTYH.humedad";

    JsonObjectRequest getRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Toast.makeText(HumedadActivity.this, "Respuesta Peticion"+response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(HumedadActivity.this, "Error Peticion: "+error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    ){

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            params.put("X-AIO-Key", "aio_oooooooo2iuCfXPK5");

            return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(getRequest);
```

Gracias.